# Manipulating a linear form into a proximal operator form

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

Given an expression:

$$\arg\min_x -\alpha p^TAx + f(x)$$

I'd like to define $v$ such that:

$$\text{prox}_{\sigma f}(v) = \arg\min_x 0.5 \|x - v\|_2^2 + \sigma f(x) = \arg \min_x -\alpha p^TAx + f(x)$$

I abuse equality above to mean the same argument.
How can I find such $v$?

Such trick is done in:

[image]

Comment: Please recheck you question. I think the arg min should range over $x$?

Comment: @gerw, good catch!

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. The term inside the first "arg min" is just "linear in $x$ plus $f$", whereas inside the prox we always have $\|x\|^2$.

Comment: @gerw, I added an example.